# Docker userns-remap permissions issue

Tags: docker

I am trying to run the docker daemon on an Ubuntu 16.04 host such that the processes within the docker container no longer run as `root`.

I have altered `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as follows

```
{
  "experimental": true,
  "bip": "192.19.77.1/24",
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "graph": "/opt/docker",
  "userns-remap": "default"
}
```

(Note that I specified the `graph` location as `/opt/docker` based on my client's requirements.)

Docker seems to have added entries as follows:

```
cat /etc/subuid
me:100000:65536
dockremap:165536:65536

cat /etc/subgid
me:100000:65536
dockremap:165536:65536
```

After this, if I try to run the daemon with `sudo dockerd`, I get the following:

```
# sudo dockerd
WARN[0000] The "graph" config file option is deprecated. Please use "data-root" instead.
WARN[0000] Running experimental build
INFO[2018-07-04T12:31:43.430653152-07:00] User namespaces: ID ranges will be mapped to subuid/subgid ranges of: dockremap:dockremap
a subdirectory in your graphroot path (/opt/docker/165536.165536) restricts access to the remapped root uid/gid; please fix by allowing 'o+x' permissions on existing directories
```

After a lot of flailing with `chown` and `chmod` the `/opt/docker` directory looks like this:

```
# ls -al
total 60
drwx--x--x 15 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jul  4 11:42 .
drwxr-s---  4 mjb       mjb       4096 Jul  4 11:32 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2    165536    165536 4096 Jul  4 11:38 165536.165536
drwx--S---  2 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jun  8 13:16 builder
drwx--s--x  3 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jun  8 13:16 containerd
drwx--S---  2 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jul  4 11:40 containers
drwx--S---  3 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jun  8 13:16 image
drwxr-s---  3 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jun  8 13:16 network
drwx--S---  3 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jul  4 11:42 overlay2
drwx--S---  4 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jun  8 13:16 plugins
drwx------  2 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jul  4 11:42 runtimes
drwx--S---  2 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jun  8 13:16 swarm
drwx------  2 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jul  4 11:42 tmp
drwx--S---  2 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jun  8 13:16 trust
drwx--S---  2 dockremap dockremap 4096 Jun  8 13:16 volumes
```

The error has persisted through many different attempts at `chown` and `chmod`.

There are many questions, similar, but none has provided me with enough insight to get this to work.

What do I need to do to get the docker daemon to start with the desired userns remapping option in place?

Comment: Did you get it working? Whats the docker version you using? and current output of command: sudo dockerd. Whats the content of the directory: /var/lib/docker, you should see the directory with gid.uid of the user defined "dockremap" in case of default. If the issue is resolved already, would be good to post for other community users.

Comment: @NSingh I made an attempt to describe my working setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have accomplished this, my `/etc/docker/daemon.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "experimental": true,
  "bip": "192.19.77.1/24",
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "graph": "/opt/docker",
  "userns-remap": "webapp:webgrp"
}
```

Note the userns-remap `"webapp:webgrp"`

My linux user namespace files look like this:

```
cat /etc/subuid
me:100000:65536
webapp:500000:65536

cat /etc/subgid
me:100000:65536
webgrp:500000:65536
```

Note that `webapp:webgrp` is mapped to `500000:500000` in the user and group namespace files.

The `/opt/docker` folder (where docker does its magic) looks like this:

`drwx--x--x  3 root    root      27 Jul 31  2018 docker`

If we look down inside that directory with `ls -al /opt/docker` we can see that docker created a directory for itself like this:

`drwx------ 15 500000 500000 200 Feb 14 21:21 500000.500000`

Another important thing is mounting volumes. If we want a directory to be mounted as a volume to a docker container we need to do this:

`chown -R 500000:500000 /the/dir/i/want/to/mount`

Inside of a docker container, this looks like 'root:root'. The docker container can then `chown` if it wants, for example my MongoDB container `chowns` a dir to `500999:500999` which inside the container is `999:999`.

I hope this helps someone.

My docker version is `Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962` on Ubuntu 16.